# How to count if there does not exist TRUE in the same category?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

Assume I have two tables:

| cameraNum | roadNum | isWorking |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | TRUE |
| 101 | 1 | FALSE |
| 102 | 1 | TRUE |
| 103 | 3 | FALSE |
| 104 | 3 | FALSE |
| 105 | 7 | TRUE |
| 106 | 7 | TRUE |
| 107 | 7 | TRUE |
| 108 | 9 | FALSE |
| 109 | 9 | FALSE |
| 110 | 9 | FALSE |

| roadNum | length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 |
| 3 | 140 |
| 7 | 110 |
| 9 | 209 |

I want to select a table like this:
If there is no camera working, I put it in the table.

| roadNum | length |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 140 |
| 9 | 209 |

I tried this below:

```
    SELECT r.roadNum, r.length
    FROM Cameras c, Road r
    WHERE c.isWorking = FALSE
        AND h.highwayNum = c.highwayNum
```

But these code only fliter there exists FALSE in isWorking.

| roadNum | length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 |
| 3 | 140 |
| 9 | 209 |

Comment: Best practice when joining tables is do to so explicitly rather than implicitly. For simple joins it will work, for more complex joins it'll fail completely or at least cause problems. GMB's answer below demonstrates an explicit join rather than an implicit one. Here is a resource for additional information if you are interested. [PostgreSQL Implicit vs Explicit joins](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgressql-implicit-vs-explicit-joins/)

Answer (score 1):

You want roads whose all cameras are not working. Here is one way to do it with aggregation and `having`:

```
select r.*
from road r
inner join camera c on c.roadNum = r.roadNum
group by r.roadNum
having not bool_or(isWorking)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/96RHxtMb=)**

| roadnum | length |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 140 |
| 9 | 209 |

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been thinking about this all morning. I'm wondering if I can use exist/not exists for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding using `not exists`, yes, you can use it. The following uses a CTE to get only the `roadnum` of those satisfying the *camera requirement* then joins that to `road`: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fd1JLRLj))

```
with no_working_caMera (roadnum) as 
     ( select distinct on (c1.roadNum) 
              c1.roadnum 
         from cameras c1
        where not c1.isworking
          and not exists (select null 
                            from  cameras c2
                           where c2.roadNum = c1.roadNum
                             and c2.isworking
                         ) 
         order by c1.roadnum
     )
select r.* 
  from no_working_camera nwc 
  join road r 
    on nwc.roadnum = r.roadnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't join, don't aggregate, just use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` in order to find roads that don't have a working camera:

```
select *
from road
where roadnum not in (select roadnum from cameras where isworking);
```

Comment: Right, but this would return roads that have no cameras at all, which *I suppose* OP doesn’t want.

Comment: This may be so. In that case just add `and roadnum in (select roadnum from cameras)`.